# Confusion Regarding TCP Socket Closure

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, kernel

Suppose we have a connection C1=(A, PortA, B, ListenPort), SockA is a blocking socket which represents A End as the client, here are my questions

1. If there is still much data in SockA's send buffer, then when it returns after calling close(SockA)? Function returns after first FIN is sent or after all data and FIN is sent out?
2. After close() is called, of these three items, SO_LINGER Timeout, TIME_WAIT Timeout, or SO_LINGER + TIME_WAIT Timeout, which item is chosen by the kernel to decide when to discard all socket even when there is much data in send buffer?
3. In what time will the PortA being set to be available again? After SO_LINGER Timeout or TIME_WAIT Timeout?
4. Suppose SO_REUSEPORT is set and before TIME_WAIT expires, another connection C2=(A, PortA, B, ListenPort) is established using the same PortA. Now if packets are sent from HostB, which connection will the kernel forward the packets to?

Answer (score 1):

> If there is still much data in SockA's send buffer, then when it returns after calling close(SockA)? Function returns after first FIN is sent or after all data and FIN is sent out?

None of the above. It returns when the FIN has been *buffered.* NB There is no difference between the alternatives you gave. The FIN follows the data.

> After close() is called, of these three items, SO_LINGER Timeout, TIME_WAIT Timeout, or SO_LINGER + TIME_WAIT Timeout, which item is chosen by the kernel to decide when to discard all socket even when there is much data in send buffer?

None of the above. The only way data is discarded is by setting linger on with a timeout of zero, which causes an RST instead of a FIN and discards the socket send buffer. In all other cases it persists until transmitted or the connection is reset.

> In what time will the PortA being set to be available again? After SO_LINGER Timeout or TIME_WAIT Timeout?

TIME_WAIT.

> Suppose SO_REUSEPORT is set

SO_REUSEPORT is for UDP. Nothing to do with TCP whatsoever.

Comment: “FIN has been buffered” , do you mean that FIN was buffered but all data in the send buffer will be discarded UNTIL the kernel detects socket's FIN and send FIN to its peer?

Comment: @Steve No, I mean what I said: 'The FIN follows the data.' FIN doesn't cause data loss. I don't even now what 'discarded until' means.